# c# converting A1 notation to R1C1 algorithm

Tags: c#

Im trying to convert A1 notation to int type row and column, 0 starting index. I got a code written in C and im trying to make a c# of it. Column is OK but I got problem in the row.

**Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format**

> row_col.Add("row", int.Parse(cellAddr + ii));

```
private Dictionary<string, int> ParseA1Notation(string cellAddr)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> row_col = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    int ii = 0, jj, colVal = 0;
    while (cellAddr[ii++] >= 'A') { };
    ii--;

    for (jj = 0; jj < ii; jj++) colVal = 26 * colVal + cellAddr[jj] - 'A' + 1;
    row_col.Add("col", colVal);
    row_col.Add("row", int.Parse(cellAddr + ii));
    return row_col;
}
```

heres the original C code..

```
void rc(char * cellAddr, int *row, int *col) {
    int ii=0, jj, colVal=0;
    while(cellAddr[ii++] >= 'A') {};
    ii--;
    // ii now points to first character of row address
    for(jj=0;jj<ii;jj++) colVal = 26*colVal + toupper(cellAddr[jj]) -'A' + 1;
    *col = colVal;
    *row = atoi(cellAddr+ii);
}
```

Comment: What does your input for `cellAddr` look like?

Comment: string.. Excel like "A1", "B2", "C3".. im trying to convert it to (0,1), (2,3).. something like that..

Comment: see if `row_col.Add("row", Int32.Parse(cellAddr.Substring(ii)))` works

Comment: Cool. Just added it as answer. Please mark it if it has answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the line `row_col.Add("row", int.Parse(cellAddr + ii))` to  `row_col.Add("row", Int32.Parse(cellAddr.Substring(ii)))`